# How can i syn wordpress user table with a stand-alone php script?

Tags: database, mysql

I have a wordpress membership site running with users already signed up. I currently installed a new php script on the same mysql database which will require existing user to signup. I would like the php script make use of the wordpress users table. Please help!

Comment: What have you done so far? With the custom script, you can connect to WP as usual.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress use a special password hash then you need to send the password and the hash to the PHP code of WordPress to know if it's valid.
This can be done with creating a new REST endpoint or with including the file "wp-includes/class-phpass.php" of WordPress and use it like this :

```
require_once "class-phpass.php";

$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$correct = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($enteredPassword, $hashFromDatabse));
// $correct contains TRUE or FALSE
```